# How to store a javascript animation as NFT

Tags: javascript, nft, ipfs

I have a generative "art" animation made with the JavaScript p5js library and I would like to upload the output of this perpetual infinite animation on pinata or another Ipfs service and sell it as an NFT. I would like to ask how can I do. Is the best practice to convert everything in an SVG + metadata? if so what can I do? Thanks for all the answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you can check out Opensea's metadata standards which have some info on SVG standards for their site: https://docs.opensea.io/docs/metadata-standards

This is what they say about the image properties of your NFT metadata

`image`:    This is the URL to the image of the item. Can be just about any type of image (including SVGs, which will be cached into PNGs by OpenSea, and even MP4s), and can be IPFS URLs or paths. We recommend using a 350 x 350 image.

`image_data`:   Raw SVG image data, if you want to generate images on the fly (not recommended). Only use this if you're not including the image parameter.`